# ArcGIS Server won’t release SDE table locks

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

My ArcGIS Server services are locking tables in SDE. This is a problem if I need to edit or overwrite them. Unfortunately the locks don't go away upon stopping the services. The only solution I have found is to restart the Linux `arcsde` service, which has many implications. Is there a better way to lose these phantom locks?

Comment: Are spatially-enabled views an option? They've worked well for me in cases where I can't have a table locked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tell ArcGIS Server not to make those locks.

In your service cfg files, add this:

```
<ServerObjectConfiguration>
...
    <Properties>
         ...
         <SchemaLockingEnabled>false</SchemaLockingEnabled>
    </Properties>
</ServerObjectConfiguration>
```

ESRI does not recommend this practice, but it should work for you.  I did this for a bunch of really big services that required a massive (thousands of layers) data update while still running.

For more info, refer to [the ESRI docs](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#cfg_file_service.htm).

Comment: It worked! Restarting map services + SDE was not enough for the changes to take effect. I also had to restart AGS + IIS. (Not sure whether AGS or IIS was the problem, but I figure either one could be caching the XML content.)

Answer (score 2):

At the UC ESRI was in fact recommending the use of the <SchemaLockingEnabled> tag, so long as you carefully consider the "Use caution..." paragraph in the documentation.