# SDE Connections during Caching

Tags: arcgis-server

I am running caching on a server using ArcGIS Server 10. It seems like it is holding SDE connections, older than 2 weeks, to the point that it has maximized connections. I am not sure why it is not freeing up resources.

What I can I do to make sure that it releases SDE connections.

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 1):

How many instances can each service create? Have you set idle time timeouts on these instances? Also is the service set to refresh at some stage during the night (12 am is the default I think)

Comment: I have nonpooled servicves with 0-10 instanaces.

Comment: I have nonpooled services with 0-10 instanaces. I have default recyclying: every 24 hours, at 12AM. How I can set idle timeout for these instances. My timeout settings are 600/60/1800 (max idle time) seconds, pretty much the default options. I am seeing that some of the conenction are as old as 2 weeks.

Comment: I have found this post that describes something similar: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/496/arcgis-server-wont-release-sde-table-locks, I am trying to see if this can resolve my issues.